# Android: one shot alarm fires repeatedly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I work on application where user can store events and set them "repeating time"
(for instance - every Monday I have a football training so i put event to app and it reminds me every Monday that I have training -- yeah something like reminder)

Event class contains only title, startTime, repeatTime and requestCode (unique number for alarms..).

I decided to use AlarmManager to schedule alarms so when alarm fire it should only do one thing - check if Event should repeat - if not just delete event from database, if yes than create a new Event, store to database and set new alarm for that event

Everything "works" fine, I mean the delete or store to database also set new alarm is working but **PROBLEM** is that when alarm fires for first time it just cannot stop, first alarm create the new alarm and new alarm is fire and it create another alarm which fire and create another and so on... like in a loop..

So what can be problem? Its not a good practice to create another alarm in BroadcastReciever? Or is something bad how i set alarm? I just want to set NO-REPEAT alarm which fire only once, do one thing and it will be done. I try to find solution almost everywhere but I was not able to find it :/

Here is my AlarmReciever

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ALARM_RECIVER_TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null && intent.getStringExtra("starttime") == null) {
            Log.i(ALARM_RECIVER_TAG, "Alarm not recieve properly");
        } else {
            handleEvents(context,intent.getLongExtra("starttime",0));
            Log.i(ALARM_RECIVER_TAG, "Alarm recieve");
        }
    }

    public void handleEvents(Context context, Long startTime) {
        DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
        Event event = dbHelper.getEvent(new Timestamp(startTime));
        if (event == null) return; //should not happenned

        if (event.getRepeatTime().equalsIgnoreCase("no repeat")) {
            dbHelper.deleteEvent(context,event.getStartTime().getTime());
            return;
        }

        Event newEvent = new Event();
        newEvent.setEventTitle(event.getEventTitle());
        newEvent.setRepeatTime(event.getRepeatTime());
        newEvent.setStartTime(CommonUtils.getDateByRepeat(event.getRepeatTime(),event.getStartTime()));

        dbHelper.deleteEvent(context,event.getStartTime().getTime());
        try {
            dbHelper.putInformation(dbHelper,newEvent);
            Log.i(ALARM_RECIVER_TAG,"everything ok");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(ALARM_RECIVER_TAG,"something is bad");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (newEvent.getStartTime() != null) {
            setRecurringAlarm(context,newEvent);
        }

    }

    public void setRecurringAlarm(Context context, Event event) {
        // set time when alarm should fire
        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, event.getSendingTime().getHours());
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, event.getSendingTime().getMinutes());
        updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, event.getSendingTime().getSeconds());

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("starttime",event.getStartTime().getTime());
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, event.getRequestCode(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

and here is how i call to set alarm from activity

```
 AlarmReceiver alarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
    alarmReceiver.setRecurringAlarm(context, event);
```

Comment: set.recurringalarm?